Azure Pipelines Replace Tokens task not preserving special characters in input string
I'm facing an issue with the Replace Tokens task in Azure Pipelines, where it's not preserving special characters in the input string.
Problem Description:
When using the Replace Tokens task in Azure Pipelines, if the input string contains special characters like $, the task appears to be removing or modifying them instead of preserving them as-is.
Example:
Input String: Example 88wLz5$fa34$!-$M
Expected Output: 88wLz5$fa34$!-$M
Actual Output: 88wLz5$!-
As you can see, the $ characters are being removed from the output string.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a new Azure Pipeline
Add a Replace Tokens task
Set the input string as 88wLz5$fa34$!-$Min pipeline library
Provide a dummy token and replacement value (e.g., TOKEN_TO_REPLACE and REPLACEMENT_VALUE)
Run the pipeline

Expected Behavior:
The Replace Tokens task should preserve the special characters ($ in this case) in the input string and provide the expected output: 88wLz5$fa34$!-$M.
Actual Behavior:
The Replace Tokens task removes or modifies the special characters ($) in the input string, resulting in an incorrect output: 88wLz5$!-.
Environment Details:

Azure DevOps Server: [your Azure DevOps server/organization URL]
Azure Pipelines version: [your Azure Pipelines version or build number]

I've tried various workarounds, such as escaping the special characters or using different tasks, but haven't found a reliable solution yet. Any help or guidance on how to preserve special characters when using the Replace Tokens task in Azure Pipelines would be greatly appreciated

I think it has nothing to do with Azure Pipelines but it's relevant to the command line. $ goes befora a variable name. That's why it disappears together with bunch of following characters. Just put it in quotes

I attempted with the Replace Tokens task, it can work fine to fill the correct and complete values for the specified tokens in the files.
Below is a sample I attempted on my side:

A file that contains the placeholder tokens need to replace, and the tokens are surrounded by {{ }}. For example, {{ TOKEN1_TO_REPLACE }} and {{ TOKEN2_TO_REPLACE }}.


Set the pipeline variables. The names of variables are same as the placeholder tokens in the file. For example, TOKEN1_TO_REPLACE and TOKEN2_TO_REPLACE.


In the pipeline configure the Replace Tokens task.



# YAML sample.

steps:
- bash: 'cat Test-Replace-Tokens.xml'
  displayName: 'Show content - Before Replace'

- task: replacetokens@6
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    sources: 'Test-Replace-Tokens.xml'
    tokenPattern: doublebraces

- bash: 'cat Test-Replace-Tokens.xml'
  displayName: 'Show content - After Replace'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: 'Test-Replace-Tokens.xml'
    artifact: tokens


Check the result. After replacing the tokens, I also published the updated file as an artifact and then download it to local to check the content. The tokens were replaced with the expected values.





